# computing the hesse matrix with multidimensional input in tensorflow

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

Hey there I'm new in this community. I started to program with tensorflow and I tried to compute the Hesse matrix of the prediction `y` and weights matrix `w` from a  feedforward neural network. My problem is that I can't shape the weights matrix because of the gradients function. I'm getting always:

> TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type .

Without shaping I can't compute the Hesse matrix of `y`,`w`.
Has someone an idea how to solve this problem.

```
def neural_network_model(data,layer,nodes,dim,nclasses):

hidden_layer = []
for i in range(layer):
    if(i == 0):
        hidden_layer.append({'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([dim, nodes[i]])),
                          'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes[i]]))})
    else:
        hidden_layer.append({'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes[i-1], nodes[i]])),
                          'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes[i]]))})

output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes[layer-1], nclasses])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nclasses])),}

l = []
for i in range(layer):
    if(i == 0):
        l.append(tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_layer[i]['weights']), hidden_layer[i]['biases']))
        l[i] = tf.nn.relu(l[i],'sigmoid')
    else:
        l.append(tf.add(tf.matmul(l[i-1],hidden_layer[i]['weights']), hidden_layer[i]['biases']))
        l[i] = tf.nn.relu(l[i],'sigmoid')

output = tf.matmul(l[layer-1],output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']


weights = []
for i in range(layer): 
    weights.append(tf.reshape(hidden_layer[i]['weights'],[-1]))
weights.append(tf.reshape(output_layer['weights'],[-1]))

def train_neural_network(data,layer,nodes,dim,nclasses,n,n2):
    gr = []
    prediction,weights2= neural_network_model(data,layer,nodes,dim,nclasses) 
    cost = tf.square(prediction-y)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    gradient = tf.gradients(prediction,weights2)
    hes = tf.hessians(prediction,weights2[0])
    train = func(n,n2)
    hm_epochs = 10
```

Comment: Please do not host images off site. Images should be embedded in your post. That said, please do not take images of code. Instead, you should copy and paste the code into a codeblock in your question.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback. Next time i will do it like that

Comment: You can edit your post, and do it right this time too. Also, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: that's a lot better thanks